# How to get a list of files in a folder with Artifactory's Java Client

Tags: artifactory

I'm looking for the equivalent of the [File List](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileList)  API in Artifactory's [Java Client](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java). Something along the lines of:

```
artifactory = ArtifactoryClientBuilder.create()
        .setUrl(url)
        .setUsername(userName)
        .setPassword(password)
        .build();
List<String> filesInFolder = artifactory.repository(repository).folder(folderPath).list();
```

Does it exist? What's the alternative if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some help on [GitHub](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java/issues/285), what worked for me is the following:

```
String aqlQuery = new AqlQueryBuilder()
        .item(AqlItem.aqlItem("repo", repositoryName))
        .item(AqlItem.aqlItem("path", folderPath))
        .build();
ArtifactoryRequest repositoryRequest = new ArtifactoryRequestImpl().apiUrl("api/search/aql")
        .method(ArtifactoryRequest.Method.POST)
        .requestType(ArtifactoryRequest.ContentType.TEXT)
        .requestBody(aqlQuery)
        .responseType(ArtifactoryRequest.ContentType.JSON);
ArtifactoryResponse artifactoryResponse = artifactory.restCall(repositoryRequest);
AqlResults aqlResults = artifactoryResponse.parseBody(AqlResults.class);
```

Where `AqlResults` is my custom POJO that contains the fields I need from the results.